# What is the difference between expect_popen( ) and fopen( ) in php

Tags: php, ssh, fopen, popen

I am new to php and trying to establish ssh connection with router. So which function "expect_popen()" or "fopen()" should I use??
What is the difference between them. Which one should I use for establishing ssh connection with router?

```
expect_popen("ssh -o ConnectTimeout=$this->connectTimeout $this-
             >userName@$this hostName -p $this->port -s netconf"); 

$this->stream = fopen("expect://ssh -o ConnectTimeout=$this->connectTimeout 
                     $this->userName@$this->hostName -p $this->port -s
                     netconf", "rw");
```

Currently I am using expect_popen() in my code, but saw this issue : https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=57918
Still not sure if I should move my code to fopen() or not.